# FOSUserBundle UserManager ignore fields

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I´m using FOSUserBundle and created a own model with a few new fields ( like deviceVersion ( string ) &  deviceType ( string ).

If i create a new User and add those specific fields, everything is fine:

```
$user = new User();
$user -> setEmail('test@some.tld');
// Default stuff
$user -> setDevicetype('Android');
$user -> setDeviceversion('4.2.2');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

echo $user->getDevicetype(); // outputs Android
echo $user->getDeviceversion(); // outputs 4.2.2
```

The Problem is, that in the Database the fields "devicetype" & "deviceversion" are NULL.

Even the query ignores those new fields completely:

```
  INSERT INTO my_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, ....
```

The columns do exist and
      php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env="dev"

creates the columns without any problems.

Any idea how to solve this?
I first tried the UserManager, still NULL, switched to manual via EM, still NULL.

Comment: Semms like it was a typical caching problem.
After restarting mysql / php5-fpm everything runned like excepted

Answer (score 1):

At your `User.orm.xml` do you have to override those fields and put the parameter `nullable=true`

Like this:

```
<field name="confirmationToken" column="confirmation_token" type="string" nullable="true" />
<field name="passwordRequestedAt" column="password_requested_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
```

Comment: So i have to overrite the User.orm.xml in my own UserBundle where i also overwrites the User.php ?

I already tried it the static way and added it directly into the Model and xml of the bundle, same result.

Comment: I extended the `User.php` of FOSUserBundle and the `User.orm.xml` and it's works here.

Comment: @Ricardo Simas OP have not identified that he is using mapping of xml,may be he is using yaml file for mapping or just using an entity

Comment: Currently i´m just using an entitiy.
I added the xml, but still no change. it gets completely ignored.i also configured it correct in my config.yml with user_class

Comment: Did you update your database after adding the `User.orm.xml` with the override parameters?

Comment: If you already updated the database, see if the columns still with the NOT NULL constraint.